# How to update a custom baseadapter after onListItemClick ?

Tags: android

When a user clicks on a list I need a way to update MyCustomAdapter such that a hash key,value pair is removed and the list is updated.

I'm really stuck down in onListItemClick can you help

thanks graham

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) { 
    //TODO Auto-generated method stub 

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SHORT click"  , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"DATA is" + map.entrySet() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  //NAME,VALUE
    //remove the key,value pair and update CustomAdapter 

    ????? 
    //end of remove entries from hashmap map   


} 


package telephone.org;



import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import telephone.org.MyService.LocalBinder;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.PhoneLookup;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;


//class 1 
public class DynamicLists extends ListActivity { 


    MyService mService;
    boolean mBound = false;


//class 2 ///////////////////////////////////
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter { 


    public HashMap<String, Integer> mData = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    private String[] mKeys;
    //constructor    
    public MyCustomAdapter(DynamicLists dynamicLists, int row, HashMap<String, Integer> map){ 
    mData = map;
    mKeys = mData.keySet().toArray(new String[map.size()]);
    Log.d(TAG, "INSIDE ADAPTER constructor HELLO WORLD " + map.entrySet()); 

}

public MyCustomAdapter(MyService mService, int row, Object map) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
//TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Log.d(TAG, "inside getview  ");
    View row=convertView;

if (row==null){
    LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
    row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
}

TextView label =(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.blocked);
label.setText(mKeys[position] +  "   " + getItem(position).toString()); //key + value 
return row;   


}



@Override
public int getCount() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mData.size();
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d(TAG, "inside getitem " + mData.get(mKeys[position])); 
    return mData.get(mKeys[position]);
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

}  //end of class 2 ////////////////////////



private static final String TAG = "DynamicList";

//class 1 

public static  HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>(); 





/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


}


@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) { 
    //TODO Auto-generated method stub 

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SHORT click"  , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"DATA is" + map.entrySet() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  //NAME,VALUE
    //remove the name,value pair 


    //end of remove entries from hashmap map   


    } 


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
     isMyServiceRunning();

}


public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    // Unbind from the service
    if (mBound) {
    unbindService(mConnection);
    mBound = false;
    }
}

private boolean isMyServiceRunning() { 
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE); 
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) { 
        if ("telephone.org.MyService".equals(service.service.getClassName())) 
        { 
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SERVICE IS RUNNING", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
            bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);  //SEE INTERACT WITH SERVICE BELOW


            return true; 
        } 
    } 
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SERVICE IS STOPPED AND IS NOT RUNNING", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return false; 
} 

//INTERACT WITH SERVICE
/** Defines callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService() */
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
@Override
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
// We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
mService = binder.getService();
mBound = true;
Set<Entry<String, Integer>> whatsup = mService.getNumbers();
//Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"NUMBER INTERACTION IS" + whatsup, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
Log.d(TAG, "ELEMENTS from service are:" + whatsup);
//Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"NUMBER OF ENTRIES IS" + whatsup.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


//convert SET BACK TO HASHMAP 
for (Entry<String,Integer> entry : whatsup) { 

    String name = null; 
    String[] projection = new String[] { 
            ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME};
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(entry.getKey())); 
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) { 
        name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
    }
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"RESOLVED NAME IS " + name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    projection = null;
    map.put(name,entry.getValue()); 
    }

//NEW CODE 
MyCustomAdapter custom = (new MyCustomAdapter(DynamicLists.this, R.layout.row, map));
setListAdapter(custom);
custom.notifyDataSetChanged();
//END NEW CODE 
}

//end CONVERT SET BACK TO HASHMAP


@Override
public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
mBound = false;
}
};
//END INTERACTION WITH SERVICE 

} //end of class 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to modify the adapter's dataset (apparently your mData) and call the `notifyDataSetChanged` method of the adapter.

Comment: Thanks Christophe, could you recommend an easy way to access mData from onListItemClick. Should I create an instance of MyCustomAdapter and then update mData ?

Comment: Or you can also retrieve the adapter with `listView.getAdapter()` that you will cast in `MyCustomAdapter`and change the mData and notify it...

Comment: what about updating the adapter from inside getView? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18584430/updated-views-in-list-item-dont-stay-updated-when-scrolling-through-listviewim/18584559#18584559