# Updated views in list item don't stay updated when scrolling through listview[IMG + SOURCE]

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener, baseadapter

**The short version of my question:** If I have a listview where each item has a button and that button causes a textview on that listitem to be updated, how do I make changes I make to the list row from a onClickListener in getView permanent?

**Detailed description of problem:** I have a listview and that listview has a "bump" button (equivalent to a "like" button on Facebook) and when a user presses this like button 3 things happen:

1. A async request is made to my api which records the "bump" by adding a record to one of my db tables. If the request is successful the api issues a response with 2 fields ( is_bumped(boolean) & bump_count(int)  )
2. If the api request was successful then we grab bumpCount from the response and use it to update the bumpTv to reflect the new total number of times that list item has been "bumped".... example: "3 Bumps"
3. If the API request was successful and isBumped=true then we update the image resource to a version of my bump icon that looks selected/pressed.

All of this works just fine at first glance, but if you "bump" a list item and then scroll all the way to the bottom of the list and then back to the top, the list item you just bumped will no longer appear to be bumped unless you refresh the entire activity. I know this has to have something to do with the data that I bind to the adapter not being updated, but how do I go about updating without refreshing the entire update?

[image]

```
package com.quothor.helpers;

import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;





public class NewLazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

 private Activity activity;
 private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
 private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
 public ImageLoader imageLoader; 
 public FragmentManager frag_manager;



 static class ViewHolder {
  TextView name;
  TextView div3;
  TextView div2;
  TextView bumpTv;
  TextView message;
  TextView commentsTv;
  SmartImageView thumb_image;
  ImageButton bumpBtn;
  ImageButton requestBtn;
  ImageButton settingsBtn;
  TextView created ;

    int position;
  }

 public NewLazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
  activity = a;
  data=d;
  inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
 }

 public NewLazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d, FragmentManager manager) {
  activity = a;
  frag_manager=manager;
  data=d;
  inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
 }

 public int getCount() {
  return data.size();
 }

 public Object getItem(int position) {
  return position;
 }

 public long getItemId(int position) {
  return position;
 }

 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  ViewHolder holder;
  HashMap<String, String> update = new HashMap<String, String>();
  update = data.get(position); 

  if(convertView==null){
   convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
   holder = new ViewHolder();

  holder.name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name); // title
  holder.div3 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.divider3); // title
  holder.div2 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.divider2); // title

  holder.bumpTv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.bump); // title
  holder.message = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.message); // artist name
  holder.commentsTv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.comments); // artist name

  holder.thumb_image = (SmartImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
  holder.bumpBtn= (ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.bump_btn);
  holder.requestBtn = (ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.hidden_btn);

  holder.settingsBtn = (ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.settings_btn);
  holder.created = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.created); // duration
  holder.bumpBtn.setTag(holder);
  holder.bumpBtn.setOnClickListener(new Bump(position, update));
  convertView.setTag(holder);

  } else {
         holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
     }



  Log.i("LazyAdapter data", String.valueOf(position)+" "+update.toString());

  if(update.get("bump_count") != null){
   holder.bumpBtn.setVisibility(holder.bumpBtn.VISIBLE);
   //holder.bumpBtn.setOnClickListener(new Bump(position, update));
   String bump_count=update.get("bump_count");
   String is_bumped=update.get("is_bumped");


   //sets bump textview
   if(bump_count.equals("0")){ 

   }else if(bump_count.equals("1")){
    holder.div3.setVisibility(holder.div3.VISIBLE);
    holder.bumpTv.setVisibility(holder.bumpTv.VISIBLE);
    holder.bumpBtn.setVisibility(holder.bumpBtn.VISIBLE);
    holder.bumpTv.setText(bump_count+" bump"); 
   }else{
    holder.div3.setVisibility(holder.div3.VISIBLE);
    holder.bumpTv.setVisibility(holder.bumpTv.VISIBLE);
    holder.bumpBtn.setVisibility(holder.bumpBtn.VISIBLE);
    holder.bumpTv.setText(bump_count+" bumps"); 

   }
   if(is_bumped.equals("true")){
    holder.bumpBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.quothor_thumb_blue);
    //bumpBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.quothor_bump_btn_bg_black);
   }else{
    holder.bumpBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.quothor_bump_icon_black);
    //bumpBtn.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default); 
   }

  }

  if(update.get("relationship_view")!=null){
   if(update.get("uid")!=TabHostFragmentActivity.loggedin_uid){
    if(update.get("relation_to_user")!=null){


     holder.requestBtn.setVisibility(holder.requestBtn.VISIBLE);

     String relation= update.get("relation_to_user");

     if(relation.equals("Friend")){
      holder.settingsBtn.setVisibility(holder.settingsBtn.VISIBLE); 
      holder.requestBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.friend_btn);

     }else if(relation.equals("Familiar")){
      holder.settingsBtn.setVisibility(holder.settingsBtn.VISIBLE); 
      holder.requestBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.familiar_btn);
     }


     holder.requestBtn.setOnClickListener(new myOnClickListener(position));
     holder.settingsBtn.setOnClickListener(new myOnClickListener(position));


    }

   }

  }



  if(update.get("created") != null){
   TextView created = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.created); // duration
   String str_created=update.get("created");
   long created_l = Long.parseLong(str_created);
   String time_ago=TimeAgo.fromPhpTime(created_l);
   created.setVisibility(convertView.VISIBLE);
   created.setText(time_ago);

  }
  if(update.get("comment_count")!=null){
   holder.div2.setVisibility(holder.div2.VISIBLE);
   holder.commentsTv.setVisibility(holder.commentsTv.VISIBLE);

   String comments = update.get("comment_count");
   if(comments.equals("0")){
    holder.commentsTv.setText("no comments");
   }else if(comments.equals("1")){
    holder.commentsTv.setText("1 comment");
   }else{
    holder.commentsTv.setText(comments+ " comments");
   }


  }else{
   holder.commentsTv.setVisibility(holder.commentsTv.INVISIBLE);

  }
  // Setting all values in listview
  holder.name.setText(update.get("name"));
  if(update.get("message") != null){
   holder.message.setText(update.get("message"));
  }else{

   holder.message.setVisibility(holder.message.INVISIBLE);
  }
  holder.thumb_image.setImageUrl(update.get("thumb_img"));
  /*
        name.setOnClickListener(new myOnClickListener(position));
        thumb_image.setOnClickListener(new myOnClickListener(position));
   */
  return convertView;
 }

 public class myOnClickListener implements OnClickListener{
  private int position;
  private String clicked_uid;
  public myOnClickListener(int position){
   this.position=position;
  }
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {

   HashMap<String, String> update = new HashMap<String, String>();
   update = data.get(position); 
   Log.i("Update Position:", update.toString());
   clicked_uid=update.get("uid");
   Log.d("Clicked UID:", clicked_uid+"");
   String relation= update.get("relation_to_user");
   String uid = update.get("uid");
   String name = update.get("name");
   String thumb_img = update.get("thumb_img");


   FragmentManager fm = frag_manager;
   EditRelationshipDialog editRelationshipDialog = new EditRelationshipDialog().newInstance(uid,relation,name,thumb_img);
   editRelationshipDialog.show(fm, "relationshipsdialog");



  }

 }


    public class Bump implements OnClickListener{
     private int position;
  private String clicked_uid;
  public Bump(int position,  HashMap<String, String> update){
      this.position=position;

     }
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
   HashMap<String, String> update = new HashMap<String, String>();
   update = data.get(position); 
   final View theview=v;
   Log.i("Update Position:", update.toString());
   String msg_id=update.get("msg_id");
   //ViewHolder mH = (ViewHolder) theview.getTag();

        // mH.message.setText("clicked");

   RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
   params.put("msg_id", msg_id);
   params.put("loggedin_uid", TabHostFragmentActivity.loggedin_uid);




   RestClient.post(TabHostFragmentActivity.token,"http://api/bump", params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable arg0, JSONObject arg1) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     super.onFailure(arg0, arg1);

     Log.i("bump request failed in lazy adapter", arg1.toString());
     Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), arg1.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(JSONObject json) {
     ViewHolder mH = (ViewHolder) theview.getTag();

     try {

      String is_bumped=json.getString("is_bumped");
      String bump_count=json.getString("bump_count");
      if(bump_count != null){ 
       if(bump_count.equals("0")){ 

       }else if(bump_count.equals("1")){
        mH.div3.setVisibility(mH.div3.VISIBLE);
        mH.bumpTv.setVisibility(mH.bumpTv.VISIBLE);
        mH.bumpBtn.setVisibility(mH.bumpBtn.VISIBLE);
        mH.bumpTv.setText(bump_count+" bump"); 
       }else{
        mH.div3.setVisibility(mH.div3.VISIBLE);
        mH.bumpTv.setVisibility(mH.bumpTv.VISIBLE);
        mH.bumpBtn.setVisibility(mH.bumpBtn.VISIBLE);
        mH.bumpTv.setText(bump_count+" bumps"); 

       }


      } 
     } catch (JSONException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
     try {
      String is_bumped=json.getString("is_bumped");

      if(is_bumped.equals("true")){
       mH.bumpBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.quothor_thumb_blue);
       //bumpBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.quothor_bump_btn_bg_black);
      }else{
       mH.bumpBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.quothor_bump_icon_black);
       //bumpBtn.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default); 
      }
     } catch (JSONException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
     }


    }
   });


  }

    }
}
```

**EDIT:** After taking the advice in the comments i was sure my list would begin functioning the way I had intended it to , but it only opened up a whole new can of hell....now for some reason if a user clicks the "bump" button anywhere in the first 6 items it works just fine, but beyond that something weird starts happening. when a user hits the bump button on one of the list items below the first 6 items it sends the wrong position and its a position somewhere between 0 and 6 ?!?!?

```
package com.quothor.helpers;

import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;




public class NewLazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

 private Activity activity;
 private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
 private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
 public ImageLoader imageLoader; 
 public FragmentManager frag_manager;



 static class ViewHolder {
  TextView name;
  TextView div3;
  TextView div2;
  TextView bumpTv;
  TextView message;
  TextView commentsTv;
  SmartImageView thumb_image;
  ImageButton bumpBtn;
  ImageButton requestBtn;
  ImageButton settingsBtn;
  TextView created ;

    int position;
  }

 public NewLazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
  activity = a;
  data=d;
  inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
 }

 public NewLazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d, FragmentManager manager) {
  activity = a;
  frag_manager=manager;
  data=d;
  inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
 }

 public int getCount() {
  return data.size();
 }

 public Object getItem(int position) {
  return position;
 }

 public long getItemId(int position) {
  return position;
 }

 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  ViewHolder holder;
  HashMap<String, String> update = new HashMap<String, String>();
  update = data.get(position); 
  Log.i("position being scrolled over", String.valueOf(position));

  if(convertView==null){
   convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
   holder = new ViewHolder();

  holder.name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name); // title
  holder.div3 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.divider3); // title
  holder.div2 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.divider2); // title

  holder.bumpTv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.bump); // title
  holder.message = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.message); // artist name
  holder.commentsTv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.comments); // artist name

  holder.thumb_image = (SmartImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
  holder.bumpBtn= (ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.bump_btn);
  holder.requestBtn = (ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.hidden_btn);

  holder.settingsBtn = (ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.settings_btn);
  holder.created = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.created); // duration
  holder.bumpBtn.setTag(holder);
  holder.bumpBtn.setOnClickListener(new Bump(position, update));
  convertView.setTag(holder);

  } else {
         holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
     }



  Log.i("LazyAdapter data", String.valueOf(position)+" "+update.toString());

  if(update.get("bump_count") != null){
   holder.bumpBtn.setVisibility(holder.bumpBtn.VISIBLE);
   //holder.bumpBtn.setOnClickListener(new Bump(position, update));
   String bump_count=update.get("bump_count");
   String is_bumped=update.get("is_bumped");


   //sets bump textview
   if(bump_count.equals("0")){ 

   }else if(bump_count.equals("1")){
    holder.div3.setVisibility(holder.div3.VISIBLE);
    holder.bumpTv.setVisibility(holder.bumpTv.VISIBLE);
    holder.bumpBtn.setVisibility(holder.bumpBtn.VISIBLE);
    holder.bumpTv.setText(bump_count+" bump"); 
   }else{
    holder.div3.setVisibility(holder.div3.VISIBLE);
    holder.bumpTv.setVisibility(holder.bumpTv.VISIBLE);
    holder.bumpBtn.setVisibility(holder.bumpBtn.VISIBLE);
    holder.bumpTv.setText(bump_count+" bumps"); 

   }
   if(is_bumped.equals("true")){
    holder.bumpBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.quothor_thumb_blue);
    //bumpBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.quothor_bump_btn_bg_black);
   }else{
    holder.bumpBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.quothor_bump_icon_black);
    //bumpBtn.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default); 
   }

  }

  if(update.get("relationship_view")!=null){
   if(update.get("uid")!=TabHostFragmentActivity.loggedin_uid){
    if(update.get("relation_to_user")!=null){


     holder.requestBtn.setVisibility(holder.requestBtn.VISIBLE);

     String relation= update.get("relation_to_user");

     if(relation.equals("Friend")){
      holder.settingsBtn.setVisibility(holder.settingsBtn.VISIBLE); 
      holder.requestBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.friend_btn);

     }else if(relation.equals("Familiar")){
      holder.settingsBtn.setVisibility(holder.settingsBtn.VISIBLE); 
      holder.requestBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.familiar_btn);
     }


     holder.requestBtn.setOnClickListener(new myOnClickListener(position));
     holder.settingsBtn.setOnClickListener(new myOnClickListener(position));


    }

   }

  }



  if(update.get("created") != null){
   TextView created = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.created); // duration
   String str_created=update.get("created");
   long created_l = Long.parseLong(str_created);
   String time_ago=TimeAgo.fromPhpTime(created_l);
   created.setVisibility(convertView.VISIBLE);
   created.setText(time_ago);

  }
  if(update.get("comment_count")!=null){
   holder.div2.setVisibility(holder.div2.VISIBLE);
   holder.commentsTv.setVisibility(holder.commentsTv.VISIBLE);

   String comments = update.get("comment_count");
   if(comments.equals("0")){
    holder.commentsTv.setText("no comments");
   }else if(comments.equals("1")){
    holder.commentsTv.setText("1 comment");
   }else{
    holder.commentsTv.setText(comments+ " comments");
   }


  }else{
   holder.commentsTv.setVisibility(holder.commentsTv.INVISIBLE);

  }
  // Setting all values in listview
  holder.name.setText(update.get("msg_id"));
  if(update.get("message") != null){
   holder.message.setText(update.get("message"));
  }else{

   holder.message.setVisibility(holder.message.INVISIBLE);
  }
  holder.thumb_image.setImageUrl(update.get("thumb_img"));
  /*
        name.setOnClickListener(new myOnClickListener(position));
        thumb_image.setOnClickListener(new myOnClickListener(position));
   */

  return convertView;
 }

 public class myOnClickListener implements OnClickListener{
  private int position;
  private String clicked_uid;
  public myOnClickListener(int position){
   this.position=position;
  }
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {

   HashMap<String, String> update = new HashMap<String, String>();
   update = data.get(position); 
   Log.i("Update Position:", update.toString());
   clicked_uid=update.get("uid");
   Log.d("Clicked UID:", clicked_uid+"");
   String relation= update.get("relation_to_user");
   String uid = update.get("uid");
   String name = update.get("name");
   String thumb_img = update.get("thumb_img");


   FragmentManager fm = frag_manager;
   EditRelationshipDialog editRelationshipDialog = new EditRelationshipDialog().newInstance(uid,relation,name,thumb_img);
   editRelationshipDialog.show(fm, "relationshipsdialog");



  }

 }


    public class Bump implements OnClickListener{
     private int position;
  private String clicked_uid;
  public Bump(int position,  HashMap<String, String> update){
      this.position=position;


     }
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
   HashMap<String, String> update = new HashMap<String, String>();
   update = data.get(position); 
   final View theview=v;
      Log.i("POSITION BEING CLICKED",String.valueOf(position));
   Log.i("Update Position:", update.toString());

   String msg_id=update.get("msg_id");
   Log.i("msg_id",msg_id);
   //ViewHolder mH = (ViewHolder) theview.getTag();

        // mH.message.setText("clicked");

   RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
   params.put("msg_id", msg_id);
   params.put("loggedin_uid", TabHostFragmentActivity.loggedin_uid);




   RestClient.post(TabHostFragmentActivity.token,"http://api/content/bump", params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable arg0, JSONObject arg1) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     super.onFailure(arg0, arg1);

     Log.i("bump request failed in lazy adapter", arg1.toString());
     Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), arg1.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(JSONObject json) {
     ViewHolder mH = (ViewHolder) theview.getTag();

     HashMap<String, String> latestUpdate = new HashMap<String, String>();
     latestUpdate = data.get(position);
     Log.i("list item being edited", latestUpdate.toString());

     try {
      String bump_count=json.getString("bump_count");
      if(bump_count != null){
       latestUpdate.put("bump_count", bump_count);
      } 
     } catch (JSONException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
     }



     try {
      String is_bumped=json.getString("is_bumped");
      latestUpdate.put("is_bumped", is_bumped);
     } catch (JSONException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
     }

     data.remove(position);
     data.add(position, latestUpdate);
     notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
   });


  }

    }
}
```

Comment: Check this out: [Listview duplicates item every 6 times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17799123/listview-duplicates-item-every-6-times).

Comment: I dont think you understand the issue completely based on the link you sent. The issue is not with the initialization of my listview. The issue is that AFTER my custom adapter has been initialized IF a user presses the "bump" button the changes made to the list item are not permanent bc when i scroll back the listview is reading from the data i originally initialized the adapter with so any changes to list items to list items are not permanent

Comment: Actually, a much milder version of your problem is discussed in the post I recommended. I do agree (now): that post won't be of help to you since you are already aware of the issue.

Comment: So, when the user interacts with the ListView items, do you update `data`?

Comment: currently it only updates the actual textview/imagebutton , not the data set. After thinking about it deeper i guess a better question that might solve this problem would be " how do i update individual key/value pairs at a given position in my data set to make my changes permanent.

Comment: Exactly. When the ListView is scrolled, `update = data.get(position);` holds obsolete data. So, whenever user interacts with your app, changes applied to widgets(TextViews, ImageViews etc.) should also be reflected in the underlying data source.

Comment: okay so how do i go about updating a single key/value pair at a specific position in my data set? ....in my onClickListener do i just grab all the old data stored for that position, change the data fields that need to be changed and then replace the entire map at the specified position in my dataset?

Comment: Example: if `update.get("bump_count");` currently returns `"0"`, and user clicks `Bump`. Inside onClick() ==> `HashMap<String, String> latestUpdate = new HashMap<String, String>();`.... `latestUpdate = data.get(position);`... `latestUpdate.put("bump_count", "1")`... `data.remove(position);`... `data.add(position, latestUpdate);`... and now if you call `notifyDataSetChanged()`, you won't have to update the UI yourself. `ListView` will do it for you.

Comment: `ListView will do it for you.` Arghh. I meant to say that the adapter's `getView()` will update the UI.

Comment: Wont the data.remove remove all the other key/value pairs that i need for that position such as "name" and "thumb_img" also stored at that position?

Comment: nevermind I get it now. Im pretty sure this is going to work so if you would like the points for the answer of this q just cut and paste ur answer and ill approve it . Thank you much sir!

Comment: Posted an answer. I would suggest that you pick any one feature (say, the Bump icon), and implement the solution fully. Once that's done, extending the solution to other features will be easy. Plus, you'll have a proof of concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the question's comments, it was established that even though the UI was being updated (based on user interaction), the underlying data used by adapter's `getView()` weren't.

Solution: Update the data source and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter. Let `getView()` handle UI updates.

Read through the comments for more information.

Comment: so it seems you not only solved my original problem , but you predicted my future problem with your original comment, i implemented the changes to the data and it compiled fine , but now i am in deed having a issues when i click "bump" on anything past the 6th position.  I know the link you originally provided probably has the answer, but im having trouble figuring out what i need to do from looking at that other thread? What did you see in my adapter that needs to be changed?

Comment: @ChuckKelly `but you predicted my future problem with your original comment`. To be honest, I kind of felt stupid when you replied with a 5 line comment to my suggested link. Anyways, I think I see the problem. Move `holder.bumpBtn.setOnClickListener(new Bump(position, update));` outside the `if-block` and after the `else-block`. So, right before `Log.i("LazyAdapter data", String.valueOf(position)+" "+update.toString());` would be fine. See if this fixes the problem. I'll explain the reason later.

Comment: yet again, you hit the nail on the head! Thank you much friend!! Are you available as a consultant? Our app has several very unique/custom activitys, 2 of which were a bit stuck on. We would love to get your take on how we should go about the effects we desire .If so email me at fresh83 at live dot com  - p.s this message will self destruct in 24 hours so that i dont get in trouble :p

Comment: @ChuckKelly I'll get in touch with you in a couple of days. It'll be great if I can help.